# How to create this Curly brackets around tikz-tree?

Tags: lyx, tikz-trees

If I'm using lyx and I have a tikz-tree, how can I create Curly brackets like those and write above them:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First attempt with `tikz` and `decorations.pathreplacing` library  to draw braces

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,minimum height=1cm]

\node (A) {$n$};
\node[below left=of A] (B){$\dfrac{n}{3}$}; 
\node[below right=of A] (C){$\dfrac{2n}{3}$}; 
\begin{scope}[node distance=1cm and 1mm]
\node[below left=of B] (D){$T\left(\vphantom{\left(\dfrac{4n}{9}\right)}\dfrac{n}{9}\right)$}; 
\node[below right=of B] (E){$T\left(\dfrac{2n}{9}\right)$}; 
\node[below left=of C] (F){$T\left(\dfrac{2n}{9}\right)$}; 
\node[below right=of C] (I){$T\left(\dfrac{4n}{9}\right)$}; 
\end{scope}

\foreach \from/\to in {A/B,A/C,B/D,B/E,C/F,C/I}
{\draw(\from)--(\to);}

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm},OliveGreen](A.45)--node[right,anchor=south west] {$\log_{3/2}n$}(I.60);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=3mm},blue](A.135)--node[right,anchor=south east] {$\log_{3}n$}(D.120);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

If you want more complexe tree you can take advantage of [forest](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest).

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm and 2cm,minimum height=1cm]

\node (A) {$n$};
\node[below left=of A] (B){$\dfrac{n}{3}$}; 
\node[below right=of A] (C){$\dfrac{2n}{3}$}; 
\node[right =1cm of B](G){$\dfrac{n}{3}$}(C);
\node[left =1cm of C](K){$\dfrac{n}{3}$}(C);
\begin{scope}[node distance=1cm and 1mm]
\node[below left=of B] (D){$T\left(\vphantom{\left(\dfrac{4n}{9}\right)}\dfrac{n}{9}\right)$}; 
\node[below right=of B] (E){$T\left(\dfrac{2n}{9}\right)$}; 
\node[below left=of C] (F){$T\left(\dfrac{2n}{9}\right)$}; 
\node[below right=of C] (I){$T\left(\dfrac{4n}{9}\right)$}; 
\end{scope}

\foreach \from/\to in {A/B,A/C,A/G,A/K,B/D,B/E,C/F,C/I}
{\draw(\from)--(\to);}

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm},OliveGreen](A.45)--node[right,anchor=south west] {$\log_{3/2}n$}(I.60);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=3mm},blue](A.135)--node[right,anchor=south east] {$\log_{3}n$}(D.120);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks!
How can I add son between `n/3` and `2n/3` ?

Comment: You can add node between `(B)` and `(C)` with `\path (B)--node{mynode}(C);`.

Comment: I meant a new  son of `A`, not connected to `B` nor to `C`

Comment: To create node below `A` with `\node[below=of A] (K){mynode};` and to connect it with `(A)`  `\draw(A)--(K);`.

Comment: oh, but the line is too long, and if I want to add 2 nodes there, it prints it one over the other one =\

Comment: If you want  more customization of your tree you can use [forest](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37828/discussion-between-salim-bou-and-mano-mini).